# R Shiny renderUI objects not showing in hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, shiny

I have a Shiny application that uses an external HTML template, CSS, and javascript, but some of the inputs are still render as Shiny objects. An example of a dropdown I'm using is below:

```
getListOfVars <- function(x){

# print names of variables
data <- read.csv(x$datapath, header = TRUE)
    names(data)
}

## dropdown of variables from header of .csv
output$varList <- renderUI({
    vars <- getListOfVars(input$file1)
    selectInput("varSelect", "", vars)
})
```

This is rendered in my HTML with the following syntax:

```
<div class="panel hidden">
    {{varSelect}}
</div>
```

I'm using javascript key press events to navigate through a few panels and the do not show on panels that have their hidden tag removed programmatically. That is, unless I press a button on the page or trigger some sort of event (key presses don't work).

Sample of my ui.R code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlTemplate("template.html",
       ...
       varSelect = uiOutput("varList")))
```

Is there a way to get the inputs to render while the div is hidden? Or trigger their rendering on load of their respective panel?

**EDIT:**

**app.R**

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlTemplate("template.html",
               fileContents = dataTableOutput("contents"),
               varSelect = uiOutput("varList"),
               listOfVars = uiOutput("independent"),
               ),
  includeCSS("styles.css")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


    data <- function(){
        inFile <- input$file1

        if (is.null(inFile))
          return("NULL")
        df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
        df <- as.data.frame(unclass(df)) 
        df
  }

  # print name of file
  output$fileName <- renderText({input$file1$name})

  getListOfVars <- function(x){
    # print names of variables
    data <- read.csv(x$datapath, header = TRUE)
    names(data)
  }

  ## dropdown of variables from header of .csv
    output$varList <- renderUI({
      vars <- getListOfVars(input$file1)
      selectInput("varSelect", "", vars)
    })

  ## checkboxes of each variable that isn't currently selected
  output$independent <- renderUI({
    data <- data()
    checkboxGroupInput("independent", "",
                       names(data)[!names(data) %in% input$varSelect],
                       selected = NULL)
  })
```

**template.html**

```
<div id="panelContainer">
  <div class="panel">
     <label class="btn btn-default" id="fileUpload"> Import Data <input id="file1" name="file1" type="file" style="display: none;" >
      </label>
   </div>

   <div class="panel hidden">
        {{varSelect}}
   </div>
   <div class="panel hidden">
       {{listOfVars}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
 var $panels = $('.panel');
 var i = 0;
 console.log($panels);
 $('body').keydown(function(e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 39) { // left
         console.log(i);
         console.log($panels.eq(i))
         $panels.eq(i).addClass("hidden");
         i++;
         $panels.eq(i).removeClass("hidden")
     }
 });
```

Comment: Please submit a fully working example (with fake data)

Comment: Okay - give me a few. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changes have been added.

Comment: styles.css is missing and I can't see where JS file is loaded

Comment: I figured it out. Had to use outputOptions(output, 'disable_ui', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)